# Details of a pre-trained model loaded from a pb file

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0, pre-trained-model

I loaded a pretrained detection model as the following, and now I want to see the details and summarize of this model. I want to find the output of this model at the layer before fully connected layer.

Is there anybody to help me?

```
def _load_model(model_path):
        detection_graph = tf.Graph()
        with detection_graph.as_default():
            od_graph_def = tf.compat.v1.GraphDef()
            with tf.compat.v2.io.gfile.GFile(model_path, 'rb') as fid:
                serialized_graph = fid.read()
                od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
                tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')
my_model = _load_model(model_path)
```